# Login failed for user domain\user in vs17

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, mdf

I have tried to open a mdf-file getting the Loging failed for user domain\user. ConnectionString to the existing mdf-file

```
<add name="NWindConnectionString" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\NWind.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried to create a mdf-file with visual studio 2017 in a .NET MVC5 project getting the Loging failed for user domain\user.

I have installed SQL Server 2014.
I can connect perfectly to the SQL Server Management Studio with my windows credentials.
SQL Server is configured to use Windows credentials.

I opened the mdf-file of the project (is a GitHub project) correctly with SQL Server Managment Studio attaching the file.

Steps to add new MDF-File to the project:

Add New Item into App_Data folder

Service-based Database -> Button Add

Then error promps

To get an idea which process I am following https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/service-based-database-file-visual-studio-bharath-gunupati

Attempt to open an existing mdf-file(NWind.mdf) in my project
[image]

Any clue what can be wrong with Visual Studio 17?
Could Be a misconfiguration of the Visual Studio?

For now I uninstalling SQL Server 2014 and installing SQL Server 2017, hope that this fix some misconfiguration of Visual Studio.

After install and unistall still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Apparently the sql server localdb installed with visualstudio was damage or something. So I run this on command line window.

```
sqllocaldb stop mssqllocaldb
sqllocaldb delete mssqllocaldb
sqllocaldb start "MSSQLLocalDB"
```

Although, my Visual Studio needed a complement to connect properly with SQL Server.

This is what actually fixed my login for user error.

In case you guys require this [Complement for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox) complement, but not sure if that was part of the solution.

Comment: You can accept this answer as correct by clicking the tick/check mark to the left hand side. When it turns green it is marked as "accepted". We welcome self-answers here.